# How to change the color of a vector image in navigationView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-menu

I need to change the color of the **menuitem icon**, I tried many ways that I found but not one of them does not work

```
 navigationView.getMenu().getItem(i).getIcon().setTint(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary));
```

or

```
Drawable drawable = navigationView.getMenu().getItem(i).getIcon();
            if(drawable != null) {
                drawable.mutate();
                drawable.setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
                SpannableString s = new SpannableString(name);
                s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Current_Theme.getInt("custom_button_arrow",ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.custom_button_arrow))), 0, s.length(), 0);
                navigationView.getMenu().getItem(i).setTitle(s);

            }
```

or

```
navigationView.getMenu().getItem(i).getIcon().setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

or

```
Drawable mWrappedDrawable = drawable.mutate();
                mWrappedDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable);
                DrawableCompat.setTint(mWrappedDrawable, Color.RED);
                DrawableCompat.setTintMode(mWrappedDrawable, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
navigationView.getMenu().getItem(i).setIcon(mWrappedDrawable);
```

, please help me

Answer (score 0):

Use `itemIconTint` property to change color of  NavigationView item icon.

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            app:itemIconTint="@color/colorPrimary" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to

```
 navigationView.setItemIconTintList(new ColorStateList(new int[][]{ new int[]{android.R.attr.state_enabled} }, new int[] {Color.RED}));
```